# Does DB2 have an "insert or update" statement?

Tags: sql, database, db2, insert-update, upsert

From my code (Java) I want to ensure that a row exists in the database (DB2) after my code is executed.

My code now does a `select` and if no result is returned it does an `insert`.  I really don't like this code since it exposes me to concurrency issues when running in a multi-threaded environment.

What I would like to do is to put this logic in DB2 instead of in my Java code.
Does DB2 have an `insert-or-update` statement? Or anything like it that I can use?

For example:

```
insertupdate into mytable values ('myid')
```

Another way of doing it would probably be to always do the insert and catch "SQL-code -803 primary key already exists", but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have one transaction per thread? DBMS are good with multiple threads, that's why transactions were invented. They would solve the concurrency issue.

Comment: That won't solve the concurrency issue because transactions only work by blocking on an already existing row. If the row does not exist, the transaction cannot block on it and so this kind of operation is still open to concurrency issues

Answer (score 44):

Yes, DB2 has the MERGE statement, which will do an UPSERT (update or insert).

```
MERGE INTO target_table USING source_table ON match-condition
{WHEN [NOT] MATCHED 
          THEN [UPDATE SET ...|DELETE|INSERT VALUES ....|SIGNAL ...]}
[ELSE IGNORE]
```

See:

<s>http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0010873.htm</s>

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/merge?lang=en

Comment: Example woud be useful: __merge into mytable using (values('col1',  'col2')) as tmp (code, name) on mytable.code = tmp.code
 when matched then update set name= col2'__

Comment: DB2 has some dated limitations with the merge statement.  #1 the stats about number of inserts/updates/deletes done with the merge are garbage and this is documented.   #2.  More importantly if you need to return an identity value from a column that auto creates an ID on insert you cannot do this with a Merge.  the IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL does not work to grab the new id associated with the insert.   I've worked as a DBA's and programmed against so many databases and DB2 is the quirkiest, most difficult, strangest, dated feature database i've ever experienced in my 25+ years of doing this.

Answer (score 19):

I found this thread because I really needed a one-liner for DB2 INSERT OR UPDATE.

The following syntax seems to work, without requiring a separate temp table.

It works by using VALUES() to create a table structure .  The SELECT * seems surplus IMHO but without it I get syntax errors.

```
MERGE INTO mytable AS mt USING (
    SELECT * FROM TABLE (
        VALUES 
            (123, 'text')
    )
) AS vt(id, val) ON (mt.id = vt.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET val = vt.val
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, val) VALUES (vt.id, vt.val)
;
```

if you have to insert more than one row, the VALUES part can be repeated without having to duplicate the rest.

```
VALUES 
    (123, 'text'),
    (456, 'more')
```

The result is a single statement that can INSERT OR UPDATE one or many rows presumably as an atomic operation.

Comment: There is a chance you want to use `SELECT 'value' name FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` instead of the `SELECT * FROM TABLE VALUES`

Comment: "presumably as an atomic operation" - this depends on your transaction isolation level, and at least for me, resulted in errors in concurrent use case with default settings. The solution was to explicitly set isolation level "repeatable read" with keyword `WITH RR`. Isolation levels in db2: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0004121.html

Comment: I am so sad that we can't use prepared statement with this request.

Answer (score 11):

This response is to hopefully fully answer the query MrSimpleMind had in [use-update-and-insert-in-same-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987691/use-update-and-insert-in-same-query) and to provide a working simple example of the DB2 MERGE statement with a scenario of inserting AND updating in one go (record with ID 2 is updated and record ID 3 inserted).

```
CREATE TABLE STAGE.TEST_TAB (  ID INTEGER,  DATE DATE,  STATUS VARCHAR(10)  );
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO TEST_TAB VALUES (1, '2013-04-14', NULL), (2, '2013-04-15', NULL); COMMIT;

MERGE INTO TEST_TAB T USING (
  SELECT
    3 NEW_ID,
    CURRENT_DATE NEW_DATE,
    'NEW' NEW_STATUS
  FROM
    SYSIBM.DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT
    2 NEW_ID,
    NULL NEW_DATE,
    'OLD' NEW_STATUS
  FROM
    SYSIBM.DUAL 
) AS S
  ON
    S.NEW_ID = T.ID
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
      (T.STATUS) = (S.NEW_STATUS)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
    (T.ID, T.DATE, T.STATUS) VALUES (S.NEW_ID, S.NEW_DATE, S.NEW_STATUS);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I would like to point out that some ibm databases use `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` as dummy table instead of `SYSIBM.DUAL`

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to execute this 2 queries. It's simpler than create a MERGE statement:

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME=xxxxx where MyID=XXX;

INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (MyField1,MyField2) values (xxx,xxxxx) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from TABLE_NAME where MyId=xxxx);
```

The first query just updateS the field you need, if the MyId exists.
The second insertS the row into db if MyId does not exist.

The result is that only one of the queries is executed in your db.

Comment: If your version of DB2 has `MERGE`, prefer that - it'll help eliminate certain potential concurrency issues.  I wouldn't automatically label this "simpler", though; you have extra overhead from dealing with two statements (that must be maintained in sync!), and it doesn't really solve the possibility of a different process inserting the row between the `UPDATE` and your own `INSERT`...

Comment: That `insert` statement is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score -3):

I started with hibernate project where hibernate allows you to saveOrUpdate().
I converted that project into JDBC project the problem was with save and update.
I wanted to save and update at the same time using JDBC.
So, I did some research and I came accross ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE :

```
String sql="Insert into tblstudent (firstName,lastName,gender) values (?,?,?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
firstName= VALUES(firstName),
lastName= VALUES(lastName),
gender= VALUES(gender)";
```

The issue with the above code was that it updated primary key twice which is true as
per mysql documentation:
The affected rows is just a return code. 1 row means you inserted, 2 means you updated, 0 means nothing happend.

I introduced id and increment it to 1. Now I was incrementing the value of id and not mysql.

```
String sql="Insert into tblstudent (id,firstName,lastName,gender) values (?,?,?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
id=id+1,
firstName= VALUES(firstName),
lastName= VALUES(lastName),
gender= VALUES(gender)";
```

The above code worked for me for both insert and update.

Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: The question was about DB/2. You're talking about MySQL. Did you actually check if your proposed Syntax is available in DB/2?