# DB2 for IBM iSeries: IF EXISTS statement syntax

Tags: syntax, if-statement, db2, ibm-midrange, exists

I am familiar with Sybase which allows queries with format: IF EXISTS () THEN ... ELSE ... END IF (or very close).  This a powerful statement that allows: "if exists, then update, else insert".

I am writing queries for DB2 on IBM iSeries box.  I have seen the CASE keyword, but I cannot make it work.  I always receive the error: "Keyword CASE not expected."

Sample:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE KEY = xxx )
THEN UPDATE MYTABLE SET VALUE = zzz WHERE KEY = xxx
ELSE INSERT INTO MYTABLE (KEY, VALUE) VALUES (xxx, zzz)
END IF
```

Is there a way to do this against DB2 on IBM iSeries?  Currently, I run two queries.  First a select, then my Java code decides to update/insert.  I would rather write a single query as my server is located far away (across the Pacific).

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330241/does-db2-have-an-insert-or-update-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB/2 on the AS/400 does not have a conditional `INSERT` / `UPDATE` statement.

You could drop the `SELECT` statement by executing an `INSERT` directly and if it fails execute the `UPDATE` statement.  Flip the order of the statements if your data is more likely to `UPDATE` than `INSERT`.

A faster option would be to create a temporary table in `QTEMP`, `INSERT` all of the records into the temporary table and then execute a bulk `UPDATE ... WHERE EXISTS` and `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS` at the end to merge all of the records into the final table.  The advantage of this method is that you can wrap all of the statements in a batch to minimize round trip communication.

Comment: Thanks I will use this solution.  It is the simplest to code and debug.

Answer (score 5):

**+UPDATE+**

DB2 for i, as of version 7.1, now has a `MERGE` statement which does what you are looking for.

```
>>-MERGE INTO--+-table-name-+--+--------------------+----------->
               '-view-name--'  '-correlation-clause-'   

  >--USING--table-reference--ON--search-condition----------------->

     .------------------------------------------------------------------------.   
     V                                                                        |   
  >----WHEN--+-----+--MATCHED--+----------------+--THEN--+-update-operation-+-+----->
             '-NOT-'           '-AND--condition-'        +-delete-operation-+     
                                                         +-insert-operation-+     
                                                         '-signal-statement-'
```

See [IBM i 7.1 InfoCenter DB2 MERGE statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzmerge.htm) reference page

Answer (score 1):

You can perform control-flow logic (IF...THEN...ELSE) in an SQL stored procedure.  Here's sample SQL source code:

```
-- Warning!  Untested code ahead.
CREATE PROCEDURE libname.UPSERT_MYTABLE (
    IN THEKEY DECIMAL(9,0),
    IN NEWVALUE CHAR(10) )
LANGUAGE SQL
MODIFIES SQL DATA

BEGIN

    DECLARE FOUND CHAR(1);

    -- Set FOUND to 'Y' if the key is found, 'N' if not.
    -- (Perhaps there's a more direct way to do it.)
    SET FOUND = 'N';
    SELECT 'Y' INTO FOUND
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE KEY = THEKEY);

    IF FOUND = 'Y' THEN

        UPDATE MYTABLE
        SET VALUE = NEWVALUE
        WHERE KEY = THEKEY;

    ELSE

        INSERT INTO MYTABLE
          (KEY, VALUE)
        VALUES
          (THEKEY, NEWVALUE);

    END IF;

END;
```

Once you create the stored procedure, you call it like you would any other stored procedure on this platform:

```
CALL UPSERT_MYTABLE( xxx, zzz );
```

Answer (score 0):

This slightly over complex piece of SQL procedure will solve your problem:

[IBM Technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21008451)

If you want to do a mass update from another table then have a look at the MERGE statement which is an incredibly powerful statement which lets you insert, update or delete depending on the values from another table.
[IBM DB2 Syntax](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0010873.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately DB2 on the AS/400 doesn't support the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: To keep the info updated, DB2 for i (AS/400) has had MERGE since mid-2010. A current release OS version is required.