# Insert into from select with multiple columns and multiple tables

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

### I need to create a SQL Trigger with Insert Statement selecting multiple columns from different tables . Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACTIV_TRG 
AFTER INSERT ON TRANS_LOG
REFERENCING NEW AS TR  
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    INSERT INTO ACTIVITIES values ( 
    (SELECT MAX(SEQNBR) FROM ACTIV_LOG where TRAN_ID = 'XXX'),
    TR.ACCOUNT,
    TR.EVENT, 
    SELECT TRAN_ID ,
    TRAN_DT ,
    TRAN_LN  FROM ACTIV_DEL where TRAN_ID = 'XXX',
    CURRENT TIMESTAMP
)
END;
```

The issue is when I tried to select more than one column in the sub query. 
I know if I separate the Sub Query like this :

```
(TRAN_ID  FROM ACTIV_DEL where TRAN_ID = 'XXX'),
(TRAN_DT  FROM ACTIV_DEL where TRAN_ID = 'XXX'),
(TRAN_LN  FROM ACTIV_DEL where TRAN_ID = 'XXX'),
```

will work but definitely there must be a better and efficient way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Definitely, there must be a better solution than this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACTIV_TRG 
AFTER INSERT ON TRANS_LOG
REFERENCING NEW AS TR  
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
   INSERT INTO ACTIVITIES values ( 
   (SELECT MAX(SEQNBR) FROM ACTIV_LOG where TRAN_ID = 'XXX'),
   TR.ACCOUNT, ---> FIELD FROM TRANS_LOG (TRIGGER SOURCE)
   TR.EVENT,   ---> FIELD FROM TRANS_LOG (TRIGGER SOURCE)
   SELECT TRAN_ID  FROM ACTIV_DEL where TRAN_ID = 'XXX',  ---> REPETING SELECT
   SELETC TRAN_DT  FROM ACTIV_DEL where TRAN_ID = 'XXX',  ---> REPETING SELECT
   SELECT TRAN_LN  FROM ACTIV_DEL where TRAN_ID = 'XXX',  ---> REPETING SELECT
   CURRENT TIMESTAMP
)
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the insert with the following select:

```
    SELECT (SELECT MAX(SEQNBR) FROM ACTIV_LOG where TRAN_ID = 'XXX'),
        TR.ACCOUNT,
        TR.EVENT,
        TRAN_ID ,
        TRAN_DT ,
        TRAN_LN,
        CURRENT TIMESTAMP
        FROM ACTIV_DEL
        where TRAN_ID = 'XXX'
```

Comment: Thanks Mary but the thing is that I  also need 3 columns from another sub Query:  SELECT    TRAN_ID ,
    TRAN_DT ,
    TRAN_LN  FROM ACTIV_DEL where TRAN_ID = 'XXX',
    CURRENT TIMESTAMP

Comment: @Bill_Buckner I think this covers perfectly your issue, since it is doing a select to the table ACTIV_DEL

Comment: Mary- but the thing is that I can't use the insert in that way because table ACTIV_DEL might not has record and I'm still need to insert the values of the table(TRANS_LOG
) affected in the trigger.

Comment: @Bill_Buckner I would check if the value exists in ACTIV_DEL if it doesn't exist I would insert a null value in those fields instead of doing the select  (check if exists [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922048/db2-for-ibm-iseries-if-exists-statement-syntax))

Comment: That's a good approach but we are running in DB2 and does not support conditional INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACTIV_TRG 
AFTER INSERT ON TRANS_LOG
REFERENCING NEW AS TR  
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    INSERT INTO ACTIVITIES 
        SELECT (SELECT MAX(f0.SEQNBR) FROM ACTIV_LOG f0 where f0.TRAN_ID = f1.TRAN_ID),
        TR.ACCOUNT,
        TR.EVENT,
        f1.TRAN_ID ,
        f1.TRAN_DT ,
        f1.TRAN_LN,
        CURRENT TIMESTAMP
        FROM ACTIV_DEL f1
        where f1.TRAN_ID = 'XXX'

END;
```

Comment: The issue is that table ACTIV_DEL might not has record and I need to insert the values of the table(TRANS_LOG ) affected in the trigger no matter if can't get TRAN_ID ,TRAN_LN and TRAN_ID from ACTIV_DEL table.