# Where not exists causing problems for insert into, db2

Tags: db2

I have a query like so:

```
insert into mySchema.myTable (award_id, cust_id) values ('blahblah', 12345)
where not exists (select * from mySchema.myOtherTable where cust_id = 12345);
```

I am getting error:

```
ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD WHERE.  TOKEN FOR <END-OF-STATEMENT> NOT ATOMIC WAS EXPECTED SQL 
Code: -199, SQL State: 42601
```

I have seen a bunch of similar queries accepted as answers, and I don't understand why it's finding issue with this.

Comment: Yes it's indeed illegal since it's INSERT and NOT SELECT

Comment: Could you provide a link to one of those answers. You're probably misreading it.

Comment: there is an answer about that in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330241/does-db2-have-an-insert-or-update-statement also here http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1560413

Comment: In your first link That insert statement mustaccio correctly points out that the query is syntactically incorrect. Look into MERGE if you haven't already, it's a very powerful statement. In the second link I can't see any similarities  with the query you tried, am I missing something?

Comment: I am familiar with merge statement, but I didn't want to use it since I would never be updating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work:

```
insert into mySchema.myTable (award_id, cust_id) 
select 'blahblah', 12345
from sysibm.sysdummy1
where not exists (select * from mySchema.myOtherTable where cust_id = 12345);
```

An alternative to sysibm.sysdummy1 would be:

```
insert into mySchema.myTable (award_id, cust_id) 
select 'blahblah', 12345
from ( values (1) )
where not exists (select * from mySchema.myOtherTable where cust_id = 12345);
```

Comment: I had just answered the same thing without noticing your post, you get the check anyways though, thanks.

Comment: I recomend that you have a look at Merge. It solves this and other problems in a nice way

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about that but you can do it like below though

```
INSERT INTO mySchema.myTable (award_id, cust_id) 
SELECT 'blahblah', 12345
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM mySchema.myOtherTable WHERE cust_id = 12345
)
```

(OR)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mySchema.myOtherTable WHERE cust_id = 12345)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mySchema.myTable (award_id, cust_id) 
    VALUES('blahblah', 12345)
END
```

Comment: So I got it to work with something similar to the first option. I'll post it in another answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into mySchema.myTable (award_id, cust_id) 
(select 'blahblah', 12345 from sysibm.sysdummy1
where not exists (select * from mySchema.myOtherTable where cust_id = 12345));
```

This ended up working.