# How to Update/Insert (Upsert) for Multiple Values DB2

Tags: db2, insert-update, upsert, db2-luw

I am trying to do an UPSERT in DB2 9.7 without creating a temporary table to merge.  I am specifying values as parameters, however I'm always getting a syntax error for the comma separating the values when I try to include more than one row of values.

```
MERGE INTO table_name AS tab 
USING (VALUES 
        (?,?), 
        (?,?)
    ) AS merge (COL1, COL2) 
    ON tab.COL1 = merge.COL1 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET tab.COL1 = merge.COL1, 
                   tab.COL2 = merge.COL2
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT (COL1, COL2) 
        VALUES (merge.COL1, merge.COL2)
```

I have also tried teknopaul's answer from [Does DB2 have an “insert or update” statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330241/does-db2-have-an-insert-or-update-statement), but have received another syntax error complaining about the use of SELECT.

Does anybody know how to correctly include a table with values in my merge, without actually creating/dropping one on the database?

Comment: this could help you  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/merge?lang=en

Comment: Are you always filling out all rows?  Or only a subset?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yes all rows. I want it to update records if they are already there, and insert them if they are not.

Comment: Don't use a reserved word for the correlation name: `AS merge (COL1, COL2)`.

Comment: @mustaccio Good point...however I'm still receiving the same error: `ERROR [42601] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "," was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "FOR )".  SQLSTATE=42601`

Comment: I don't know, this works just fine in version 10.5. Some syntax restrictions might have been relaxed since 9.7. Try adding `TABLE`: `USING TABLE (VALUES ... ) AS m (COL1, COL2)`

Comment: @mustaccio `ERROR [42601] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0199N  The use of the reserved word "TABLE" following "" is not valid.  Expected tokens may include:  "(".  SQLSTATE=42601` The original code above works on a different server.  The difference is it's not on a mainframe...

Comment: Which version/platform are you on? There's no DB2 version 9.7 for z/OS.

Comment: @mustaccio DB2 8.2.1 I belive

Comment: Neither DB2 8 for z/OS, nor DB2 8.x for LUW supported the `MERGE` statement. May be you need to figure out what version on what platform you are dealing with before wasting any more time. You stated 9.7 (assuming LUW) in the question, then said it is "8.2.1" on mainframe in the comments.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you need something like `USING (SELECT * FROM VALUES ( ...) ) AS ...`