# Facing "Row not found for MERGE" Error in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm attempting to use a MERGE statement to update records in a physical file on an iSeries or AS400 running V7R1.

The issue that I am having is when attempting to use the merge on the test table, I get a `Row not found for MERGE. SQLSTATE=02000` warning very similar to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962621/db2-merge-upsert-gets-row-not-found-for-merge-error).

The main difference in my issue is that I started by creating a copy of my test table to preserve the data, and then using the merge to update. The merge worked against the copy created with `CPYF`. When I was satisfied the merge was working as expected, I pointed it to the proper test file and upon execution, received the warning below.

```
SQL State: 02000
Vendor Code: 100 Message: [SQL0100] Row not found for MERGE.
```

The target table is a membered physical file with an alias over it. For example, DOUG/MYDATA(F901), to create the alias I ran the following:

```
CREATE ALIAS DOUG.MYDATA901 FOR DOUG.MYDATA(F901);
```

Query that is not updating is below:

```
MERGE INTO DOUG.MYDATA901 TGT USING DOUG.TEST01 SRC
    ON TGT.PREC = SRC.PREC
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TGT.PQDS = TGT.PQDS - SRC.TTL_DIST;
```

However, when I make a copy of the file I'd like to update, the merge works...

```
CPYF FROMFILE(DOUG/MYDATA) TOFILE(DOUG/BUMYDATA) FROMMBR(F901) MBROPT(*REPLACE) CRTFILE(*YES) OUTFMT(*CHAR)
```

Merge code yields modified records:

```
MERGE INTO DOUG.BUMYDATA TGT USING DOUG.TEST01 SRC
    ON TGT.PREC = SRC.PREC
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TGT.PQDS = TGT.PQDS - SRC.TTL_DIST;
```

I validated that the source and copy, when used in a select with an inner join, does in fact yield results:

```
SELECT *
FROM DOUG.MYDATA901 TGT
JOIN DOUG.BUMYDATA SRC ON TGT.PREC = SRC.PREC;
```

Why would the MERGE work for the copied data but not the source table I created the copy from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're making your copy, you're only copying a single member of the file...`FROMMBR(F901)`

To copy all members, you'd need to use `FROMMBR(*ALL) TOMBR(*FROMMBR)`

I'm not aware, nor could I find any documentation, of any limitation of `MERGE` for multi-member files.  I did find the following in the [v7.1 SQL Reference for ALIAS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzch2alias.htm)

> An alias that refers to an individual partition of a table or member of a database file can only be used in a select statement, CREATE INDEX, DELETE, INSERT, MERGE, SELECT INTO, SET variable, UPDATE, or VALUES INTO statement.

So it seems the `ALIAS` should have worked, however, there are change markers in the docs around that block.  `MERGE` was added at 7.1, so the change markers might be from the initial enhancement, or perhaps `ALIAS` support was added a bit later.

I'd recommend asking IBM, but 7.1 is out of support.

You could create a copy of your aliased file in QTEMP with data and merge your updates into that file. Then use QSYS2.QCMDEXC to run a CPYF command and replace that data in your physical file member.