# DB2 SQL Query for condition check then update else insert

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with two keys x,y. So when ever I insert into table I have to check if x and y combo already exists. if so then I have to update else insert. Can any one please help?

it should be something like

if "keys exisys"
then
update other columns
else
insert
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does DB2 have an "insert or update" statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330241/does-db2-have-an-insert-or-update-statement)

Answer (score 1):

The [MERGE statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html) performs this function.